# Disable APK in User space

Tags: android, apk, disable

I have 2 APKs from 2 vendors and both of APKs are persistent. Since these are persistent, these would be running from the boot-up. My requirement is that based on the device node, I need to disable an APK. How to do this, does Google provide any mechanism for this?

Comment: what is Persistent ?

Comment: APK is set as persistent

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.